# Get proper alignment in the code in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, code-editor

I am using PhpStorm. And I don't like the way it handles line breaks. It just sends the code to the extreme left, but I want it to be aligned to the tag.

Below is the image which shows PhpStorm vs Notepad++. I like the way Notepad++ handles the alignment of the code. I want PhpStorm to do exactly that. I tried changing settings in Editor=> code styles, but could not get what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General`
2. `Soft Wraps` section -- use the settings there -- as simple as that.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Could not notice that in the sea of options.